# Find multiple objects by attribute values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Products.

Products have unique sizes. Sizes are attributes.

I want to change the status of Products with sizes 10, 20 and 30 exclusively.

How do I query them in one go?

I looking for something as simple as:

```
Products.find_by(size: [10, 20, 30])
```

Comment: What is size? an attribute on the model?  Another model? If an attribute what you've put should work

Comment: An attribute on the model

Comment: This shows no research. If you read the ActiveRecord docs, or simply play around in the Rails console, you would easily find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can use [`#update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class) and [`#update`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update)

```
# if you don't want to confirm validation
Products.where(size: [10, 20, 30]).update_all(status : 'x')
# if you do want to confirm validation
Products.where(size: [10, 20, 30]).find_each do |product|
 product.update(status : 'x')
end
```